# How can I insert more than 32KB data to a column in DB2?

Tags: database, db2

I have tried to insert in clob data type more than 32k byte data but getting error:-

> Statement Execute Failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0102N  The string constant beginning with "Hi good day team: We had been requested to Add Anniel to all" is too long.  SQLSTATE=54002 SQLCODE=-102

Please find my DDL statement:-

```
CREATE TABLE "DB2IDEV "."CHANGE"  (
      "TICKET_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL ,
      "SHORTDESC" VARCHAR(5000 OCTETS) NOT NULL ,
      "LONGDESC" CLOB(2147483647 OCTETS) LOGGED NOT COMPACT ,
      "RELEASENUM" VARCHAR(12 OCTETS) WITH DEFAULT NULL ,
      "ISSOFTDELETED" INTEGER NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT 0 ,
      "CREATETIMESTAMP" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP ,
      "LASTUPDATETIMESTAMP" TIMESTAMP WITH DEFAULT NULL )  
     IN "TABLESPACE" 
     ORGANIZE BY ROW  ;

INSERT INTO DB2IDEV.Change ( 
    Ticket_ID,shortDesc,longDesc,releaseNum,isSoftDeleted, 
    createTimeStamp,lastUpdateTimeStamp) 
    VALUES (
        '296129',
        'High Cisco Adaptive Security Appliance Remote Code Execution and Denial of Service Vulnerabilit',
        '<Some long data around 50KB in size>',
        NULL, '0','2018-02-07 02:11:50',NULL
    )
```

Comment: You need to improve your question. (1) you tag python but show no python in the question, so that is confusing. (2) you give an incomplete code sample , (missing tablespace definitions) and you fail to qualify the INSERT with the schema-name, and (3) if you are wise, you will put the table in one tablespace and use LONG IN "LOB" so that the longdesc column will be in a dedicated tablespace that's different from the tablespace containing the remaining columns. On a properly configured database, your DDL and INSERT statements complete successfully.

Comment: Db2 does not have CLOB literals; the value you supply for the CLOB column is treated as a character literal, which cannot exceed 32672 bytes in length as the error message tells you. You need to insert CLOB values programmatically by binding them to statement parameters.

Comment: I am using python programming language so please help me how to handle this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL0102N](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic1.html#sql0102n):

> Explanation
>
> One of the following has occurred:
>
> ...
>       The string constant beginning with string has a length greater than 32672 bytes. Character strings with lengths greater than 32672
>   bytes or graphic strings with lengths greater than 16336 characters
>   can be specified only through assignment from host variables. Note
>   that other servers in the DB2 family of products may specify a
>   different size limit for character strings. Consult the documentation
>   for the appropriate database product for details.

You must use a corresponding variable for such a long constant.
Something like this:

```
ibm_db_conn = ibm_db.connect(...)
sql = """INSERT INTO DB2IDEV.Change ( 
    Ticket_ID,shortDesc,longDesc,releaseNum,isSoftDeleted, 
    createTimeStamp,lastUpdateTimeStamp) 
    VALUES (
        '296129',
        'High Cisco Adaptive Security Appliance Remote Code Execution and Denial of Service Vulnerabilit',
        ?,
        NULL, '0','2018-02-07 02:11:50',NULL
    )"""
stmt = ibm_db.prepare(ibm_db_conn, sql)
clob='<Some long data around 50KB in size>'
ibm_db.bind_param(stmt, 1, clob)
ibm_db.execute(stmt)
```

Comment: Could you please tell me which variable i can use?
I am using python as a programming language

Comment: @AmanAgrawal Code example added.

Comment: Thank you Mark, solution worked perfectly